# Third-party SDKs and thread-safety

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, slack-api

Let's say I have a multi-threaded application which needs to send messages to Slack. There's an official Slack SDK for Python, but there's not a single word about the thread-safety in its docs.

Do I have the right to freely use a **single instance** of Slack client across my application or does it need to be on a per-thread basis?

What problems can I run into if I stick to the former approach?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the source code for the slack client:

https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/blob/main/slack_sdk/web/client.py

The safest way to proceed will be to use 'per thread' basis.

 If you really know what you are doing, may be you can use 'Single' instance and make it thread safe by using locks (other Synchronization mechanisms).

You can also reach out to slack: https://slack.com/intl/en-in/help/requests/new